# A step in uniform continuity of $\sin(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Using come nice theorems, we can show that $\sin(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ (using mean value theorem).

But I was trying to pass to this result from definition: $\sin x-\sin y=2\cos(\frac{x+y}{2})\sin(\frac{x-y}{2})$.

Therefore,
$$
|\sin(x)-\sin(y)|\le 2|\sin(\frac{x-y}{2})|.
$$
Next, I tried to see whether we can say that $\sin(\frac{x-y}{2})\le \frac{x-y}{2}$ when $(x-y)$ is small (and positive).

There are similar questions on this site, which show that $\sin(\alpha)\le \alpha$ for small positive $\alpha$, most of which rely on derivatives or integration etc.

**Q.** Can we show that  $\sin(t)\le t$ for small positive values of $t$ using elementary results, which do not rely on derivatives, integration or advanced such techniques? [This will allows us to conclude uniform continuity of $\sin.$]

---

**Note:** I know that the uniform continuity if $\sin$ can be shown using MVT, or $\sin x\le x$  for positive $x$ can be proved using derivatives: but, I am trying to prove the assertion in above question by elementary techniques ($=$not including derivatives, for example).

Comment: Draw $\sin x$ in the first quadrant of the unit circle and compare it to the arc-length ($=x$).

Comment: SL Loney proves it from the very beginnig in his book plane trigonometry

Comment: Notice that $|\sin(x)|\leq |x|$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$.